# Error canonicalCode: INVALID_ARGUMENT, "errorMessage": "`npm_install` had stderr output while firebase deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm deploying my nodeJS code with firebase, If I do firebase serve on local machine it works fine, but when I do firebase deploy it gives me multiple errors.

1. {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`npm_install` had stderr output.....}}

   if i resolve this issue then i get.
2. gen_package_lock` had stderr output.

I am not able to deploy firebase.
I am using node version >12 and integrated firebase with that. Stuck on this,

Tried with removing package-lock.json as well.

ERROR:-

Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`npm_install` had stderr output:\nnpm ERR! cb() never called!\n\nnpm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:\nnpm ERR!     https://npm.community\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2019-12-13T07_06_14_773Z-debug.log\n\nerror: `npm_install` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "8042D85F"}}

Expecting some solutions to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full errors, not partial errors where we are left to guess what the actual problem is.  It's also helpful to see code and configuration that reproduces the issue.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is the full log from error 1 or 2? Have you solved error 1 as you said? if so how? Also notice that the latest available runtime is nodeJS 10 as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) ,  you should check that your package.json looks like the one in the docs since the error may come from that.